# Use iOS shortcut to schedule an email to myself

Tags: ios, email, shortcuts-app

Is it possible to create an iOS shortcut that will automatically send an email after a defined period of time, in iOS 14?

I’ve tried using the “get time between dates” to set “current time plus four hours” as a variable, but the Wait command in scripting only seems to accept seconds as an input.

I have to take medication every four hours for ADD and for a circulation problem. But I tend to forget as I easily loose track of time, as ADD interferes with how I perceive time.

I have a shortcut that sets a timer to run for four hours when I run it. But if my phone is on “do not disturb” I miss the notifications. I’d like the emails as a backup notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I was able to do this, using the following steps.

- Create a new calendar in Google Calendar (TempCal) that is set to email reminder notifications.
- Link Google Account to iOS, to allow iOS Calendar app can access and edit TempCal.
- Create a new shortcut, with these steps:
- Adjust date - Add [time] to current event.
- Add Calendar Event - Add [event name] from Adjusted Date to Adjusted Date to TempCal

When the event occurs, Google Calender emails me.

I made another shortcut to clear TempCal’s events. I set an automation to run this shortcut every evening.

1. Find all Calendar events when start date is in last 48 hours and Calendar is TempCal
2. Choose from Calendar events (select all initially and select multiple options checked)
3. Remove Calendar events - chosen events.